# Questions on Openstack networking (Neutron) configuration

Tags: kubernetes, openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron, vxlan

newbie here who's trying to understand Openstack networking topic.

**My setup:**

I have 3 physical machines with Openstack installed and running:

- **controller** (with *Keystone, Glance, Placement, Neutron, Nova, Heat* and *Magnum* installed)

- **compute** (with *Nova* installed)

- **block storage** (with *Cinder* installed)

​

These 3 machines are physically connected (through Ethernet cable) to a router inside the same LAN (with for example addresses 192.168.x.y) , so I don't have a management and a provider network as suggested in Openstack documentation, but  I have only a single network.
All installations went good, I am able to create instances and all works correctly.

Now, I have installed Heat and Magnum on my controller to use K8s with Openstack, and I am having some issues during the cluster deployment and I think they're related also to my network configuration.

​

In fact, I am using the ml2 plugin and the Linux Bridge, but I wasn't able to create a VXLAN or a router, or a Floating IP (it doesn't exist the option to create it even in my Horizon dashboard) because they were disabled in my neutron.conf file (I have followed [this guide](https://ruffell.nz/programming/writeups/2020/02/13/deploying-a-openstack-cluster-in-ubuntu-19.10.html) during my installation, so the configurations for Neutron are pretty much the same (remember I have only one network).

​

Now, I was reading [this](https://docs.openstack.org/neutron/2023.2/install/controller-install-ubuntu.html) from Openstack documentation, and I think that I must have been followed the "Network Option 2: Self-service network" (in the Configure Network options paragraph) for my Neutron installation.

​

**So my questions are:**

**1)** Is the "Network Option 2: Self-service network" the correct network configuration I have to follow in my specific case for my setup?

**2)** To modify my neutron.conf file with the new options, I have to delete the Neutron DB in Keystone and repopulate it at the end? What are the correct steps to follow?
**3)** To create my k8s cluster with Magnum do I need to create a VXLAN, with routers to have also external Floating IPs, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the "Network Option 2: Self-service network" the correct network configuration I have to follow in my specific case for my setup?

- Yes, "Network Option 2: Self-service network" is the appropriate configuration for your single network scenario.

> To modify my neutron.conf file with the new options, I have to delete the Neutron DB in Keystone and repopulate it at the end? What are the correct steps to follow?

- You don't have to delete the Neutron DB, you can just modify the `neutron.conf` (make sure to backup first!) then restart the neutron service by [running the commands from the official docs](https://docs.openstack.org/neutron/2023.2/install/controller-install-ubuntu.html#finalize-installation):

**Restart the Compute API service:**

`service nova-api restart`

**Restart the Networking services.**

```
service neutron-server restart 

service neutron-openvswitch-agent restart 

service neutron-dhcp-agent restart 

service neutron-metadata-agent restart

service neutron-l3-agent restart
```

> To create my k8s cluster with Magnum do I need to create a VXLAN, with routers to have also external Floating IPs, right?

- Deploying your Kubernetes cluster with Magnum without immediate VXLAN or floating IP configurations is feasible if external access isn't a current requirement, focusing on internal cluster communication and operations. However, considering the dynamic needs of Kubernetes workloads and potential future requirements for external connectivity, it's advisable to plan for enabling VXLANs for network isolation and floating IPs for external service exposure.